Al generar PDF las imgenes que no tienen fondo el borde es mas grueso deberia generar todos bordes a los imagenes de 2px
images.forEach((image, index) => {
      if (index !== 0 && index % (itemsPerRow * maxRowsPerPage) === 0) {
        doc.addPage();
        addBackgroundAndText();
        addLogo(logoImg); // Agrega logo siempre que se crea una nueva página.
      }

      let x = 7 + (index % itemsPerRow) * 50;
      let rows = Math.floor((index / itemsPerRow) % maxRowsPerPage);
      let y = 55 + rows * 60 + yOffset + (rows * 5);

      const imageSrc = image.src;

      doc.setDrawColor(2, 184, 224); // Establece el color del borde
      doc.setLineWidth(2); // Establece el ancho del borde
      doc.rect(x, y, 47, 47); // Dibuja el borde alrededor de la imagen

      doc.addImage(imageSrc, "JPEG", x, y, 47, 47);
      y += 47; //margen entre imagenes y textos**


Debes agregar un [MCVE] que muestre el problema que describes.
